# Android canvas game, game speed

Tags: android, canvas

I have a simple function that increases the speed of my object in the screen:

```
float Velocity = 10;
float MaxVelocity = 100;
float VelocityGiven = 0;

RectF position = new RectF(ScreenHeight/2, ScreenWidth,0,0);

public void update()
{
    if(VelocityGiven < MaxVelocity)
    {
           Position.left -= Velocity;
           VelocityGiven += Velocity;
    }

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
        canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap,Position,null);
}
```

But depending on the phone screen size, or pixel density, this function moves the object too fast or too slow.

if I try that on a galaxy S4, witch has a really big screen resolution, the object goes slowly.

But if I try it on a low end device (small screens), the object goes very fast,
What can I do to avoid that?

I already have my FPS controlled, on every phone, this runs at 30 FPS. so it's not about the update ratio.

Comment: no need to write everything bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you wish to do exactly. One simple approach would be to make everything proportional to screen size. For instance:

```
Position.left -= Velocity * getWidth() / REFERENCE_WIDTH;
```

where REFENRENCE_WIDTH corresponds to a screen resolution where your app behaves as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with density independent units. That way it moves the same relative amount no matter what the pixel size is. To do this, decide how "big" your area is going to be. For example, to fix your width at a *logical* 1000 units:

```
float scaleWidth = (screenWidth / 1000);
float velocity = 10 * scaleWidth;
float maxVelocity = 100 * scaleWidth;
```

This would mean that no matter how wide the display actually is, at max velocity it would take 10 movements to go all the way across.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best to move your objects based on a grid system independent of the screen size. You could you meters, feet, or what ever works as your unit. Then get the screen size and screen resolution of the device and figure out what the relationship is. If your object moves one foot then how many pixels is that on the device. Based on resolution.

Here is a very general overview on screen sizes for android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

There are probably a lot more, and better, places to look for getting the device resolution and size.

Hope that at least gets you started :)